# Python list assignment out of range after initializing multidimensional list

Tags: python, list

So, I'm trying to work with multidimensional lists to make a map for an ASCII game. I have code to initialize the list,

```
mapData = [[[0 for m in range(3)] for x in range(32)] for y in range(32)]
```

then I try to access and change a value in the variable using this code,

```
mapData[0][5][5] = 1
```

and get this error message,

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I've tried many things, but can't figure anything out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your innermost list has only *three* cells, so trying to access `[5]` on it won't work.

The indices go from outermost (with 32 entries) to innermost (with 3 entries). If you expected your innermost list to have 6 or more cells, you need to adjust your `for m in range(3)` loop.

If you expected to index the first cell of the innermost list, perhaps you needed to reverse the indices:

```
mapData[5][5][0] = 1
```

To spell it out some more:

- `mapData[0]` returns the first element of the outermost list, generated by the `for y in range(32)` loop in your nested list comprehensions.
- `[5]` in `mapData[0][5]` then accesses the 6th element of the previous result, a list from the `for x in range(32)` loop.
- `[5]` in `mapData[0][5][5]` tries to index the innermost list, one of the list objects generated by `[0 for m in range(3)]`. Because those lists only have 3 `0` values each, an `IndexError` exception is raised.